# Is there a way to check php settings in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need to check if the server (Apache) allows `php_value` to be used in .htaccess. Some hosting providers disallow it. Is there a way to check if it is allowed in .htaccess file?

For example something like this:

```
<IfPHPValueEnabled>
php_value max_input_vars 10000
</IfPHPValueEnabled>
```

Comment: `$value = ini_get('max_input_vars');` but you won't know where it was defined.

Comment: The question is not exactly about **max_input_vars**, sorry for confusing. I need to know if the setting **php_value** is possible to be used in .htaccess. Some hostings disallow it.

Comment: Is this a library that you are expecting to distribute? Have you tried setting it in the `.htaccess` file and then validating when the PHP code runs (perhaps trigger a warning message to notify the user of an issue with the value?)

Comment: As I know using **php_value** and **php_flag** in .htaccess on servers that disallows it causes errors. That's why I need to check if it's allowed first.

The reason I want to use it is to modify .htaccess programmatically. In case it's not possible my app will ask user to change php setting manually.

Comment: Have you tried using a php_info(); file? It gives you all the details...

Comment: I didn't because I don't understand what exactly I should search for. Actually I don't want to parse the file to find an answer but use conditional logic right in .htaccess.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't really know this. Note that it may not fail with Apache >= 2.4 and [`Nonfatal` option of `AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Answer (score 1):

The answer I need is here http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

> When using PHP as an Apache module, you can also change the configuration settings using directives in Apache configuration files (e.g. httpd.conf) and .htaccess files. You will need "AllowOverride Options" or "AllowOverride All" privileges to do so.

Use conditional for **php_value** directive

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value max_input_vars 10000
</IfModule>
```

Comment: PHP may be enabled as a module (this is what IfModule tests) but the use of php_(value|flag) may still be forbidden (as you quoted - if `AllowOverride` doesn't include `Options`). Besides, for PHP 7, mod_php5.c will become mod_php7.c.